# Deny access to folder's content if not logged in

Tags: php, indexing, passwords

Here is the current scenario:

I have an `index.php` file located at `./dl/` that lists the files in a folder named `./dl-meta/`, using the `glob` function. It works pretty well.

The thing is, I would also like to password protect my files. I took a look at Apache's folder protect utilities, tho upon further inspection I realized that someone could easily brute force their way into my files. (I also saw that the password menu looked quite bad). So, instead of using Apache's rules, I tried making my own folder protect script in PHP, using session variables.

...The login script I crafted does a great job protecting my **PHP** files. Once the session is started, I can simply call this bit of code at the start of my PHP pages located at `/dl-meta/` to see if the user has the right to view the page:

```
if($_SESSION['login'] === false){
    echo "Access denied :(";
    die();
}
```

Obviously, I can't run this piece of code for files like `video.mp4` (AKA I can't deny access to `video.mp4` if the user is not logged in).

Is there some way I can deny access for non-PHP files when the user is not logged in?

or maybe...

Should I obfuscate the `/dl-meta/` folder? If so, how could I achieve this without breaking my file indexer and `/dl-meta/`'s folder hierarchy? Keep in mind that there are multiple subfolders in there...

Thanks for the read, SO! Feel free to ask for my code if you think it can help.

Comment: Any tips anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

Using `readfile();` I can make it so im able to download a specific file, from another location. Heres an example:

```
$path = "./files/video.mp4";
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($path)); //Tell the browser to interpret as an .mp4 file
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($path).'"'); //Change name of file (cool if you want to add some kind of watermark to your filenames)
readfile("../dl-meta/".$path); //Distribute the damn thing
```

Using the above code will make the client download the file/play it like if you directly accessed the resource. AKA you can download files from /script/file.php without revealing the URL of the actual file.

My goal is accomplished: I can protect files like `video.mp4` behind a hand made PHP login wall.

Tho, some questions still remain unanswered.. Will this code make the downloads slower/use more system resources than vanilla direct downloading?

Bigger 5gb 2 hour MP4 files dont even load anymore... Any tips with that please?